# Modifying WebAppBuilder "LayerList' widget to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've downloaded the developer version of the Web app builder and installed in on my machine.
I can open up the widget '\LayerList\LayerListView.js', and I have been exploring the source code.

I would like to be able to modify the code in order to have a combination of both radio buttons, and check boxes.  I am fairly new to javascript programming, so my knowledge doesn't go much beyond being able to copy / paste and hack basic code.

**Functionality needed:**

- By clicking a check box, it will enable or disable a map service
- By clicking a radio button, it will enable a map service, while turning off other map services that are also exposed as radio buttons.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I'm in the same boat and looking to do the same thing but am having difficulty finding any documentation.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have to play with JSON file. This link might be of some help:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/126201

Comment: Don't just include a link, write some explanation that makes your answer complete and reasonably self-contained. What does one have to do to the JSON?

Comment: I agree with @RichardLaw, unfortunately this comment doesn't help in the slightest with regards to the question on radio buttons